# how to tell if Ceph rules really direct input to SSD?

Tags: ceph

I have a Ceph cluster, and created rules as well as Pools.  After words I assigned these pools to rules created for this.  What I want to know is how can I be sure that it actually works as advertised?

Primarily I want to know that data is truly being written to SAS drives and not SSD, except when I want to.  Is there anyway to get beyond the pool definition and look at the block device itself to see where data was written.

Reason I am asking this is because the performance is exceptionally fast and about the same on both pools.  This is possible (20G connection, small file), but want to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ceph osd map](http://ceph.com/docs/hammer/rados/operations/control/#osd-subsystem) command shows which OSD is used when storing an object in a pool. For instance

```
$ ceph osd map rbd OBJECT
osdmap e11 pool 'rbd' (0) object 'OBJECT' -> 
         pg 0.383caa09 (0.1) -> up ([2,0,1], p2) acting ([2,0,1], p2)
```

tells you that `[2,0,1]` is the list of OSD id used to store OBJECT and its replicas, in the `rbd` pool. With the [ceph osd tree](http://ceph.com/docs/hammer/rados/operations/control/#osd-subsystem) command you can then verify which device is used by a given OSD id:

```
$ ceph osd tree
ID WEIGHT  TYPE NAME     UP/DOWN REWEIGHT PRIMARY-AFFINITY 
-1 3.00000 root default                                    
-2 3.00000     host fold                                   
 0 1.00000         osd.0      up  1.00000          1.00000 
 1 1.00000         osd.1      up  1.00000          1.00000 
 2 1.00000         osd.2      up  1.00000          1.00000
```

In this example we learn that `osd.0, osd.1` and `osd.2` are on the host `fold`. In the case of a separation between SAS disks and SATA disks, the `ceph osd tree` command will provide you with a similar information.

Comment: First of thank you:
Here is what I got:
ceph osd map rbd test.img
osdmap e69 pool 'rbd' (0) object 'test.img' -> pg 0.37ff1498 (0.18) -> up ([], p-1) acting ([], p-1

Now I know the object is actually there, but it isn't displaying how you indicated :(